# What is the connection between CRF and Logistics Regression?

Tags: logistic, conditional-probability, graphical-model, conditional-random-field

Logistic regression seems to be a simple version of Conditional Random field, I am unable to figure out how. Perhaps my fundamentals are shaky.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63826/how-conditional-random-fields-and-logistic-regression-could-be-the-same